# Calculating a formula with pandas objects

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing a following problem. I have a DataFrame

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'a.b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [5, 6, 7], 'd': [8, 9, 10]})
```

I am reading the following string from a config data

```
some_text = "-a.b + c - d"
```

is there a possibility to calculate the formula in some_text variable using Series from `my_df(df column)` as arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pd.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) but you need to change the column names:

```
my_df.columns=my_df.columns.str.replace('.','_')
my_df.eval(some_text.replace('.','_'))
0   -4
1   -5
2   -6
dtype: int64
```

Comment: `my_df.eval(some_text.replace('.','_'))` rather than change the text